# Refuse Keep Alive from client

Tags: http, webserver, http-1.1

I am writing a server that answers to HTTP requests, and it doesn't need to support keep alive connections (this was requested in the specification), and I was wondering what's that correct way to *refuse* a client request with the keep alive header.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My http1.1 is a little rusty, but off the top of my head, sending a `Connection: Close` header back in the response should do the trick. Not a refusal of the request... just a note to the client that we're going to close the connection despite the keep alive header.

Alternatively, you could just force an http1.0 response which has no concept of keep alive.